# Vaadin 6 : RichTextArea and remove formatting

Tags: excel, jakarta-ee, vaadin6, richtextarea

It's been a while that I've been reported about a problem on the software I'm on charge. I will try to explain it as much detailed as possible (Sorry if my english seems bad to you by the way ^^').

**Context** : The software has been developed as a Web Application (Java EE) + the framework Vaadin 6 (not 7). Since this project exists for about 4 or 5 years, the technology used isn't the newest but it's currently ok. This software is used by our internal clients so about a 70 users are using it per day. I'm on charge of this project for 9 months now.

**Problem** : Often, users copy some info (words, tables and so on) from others sources like a Word Document, or a PowerPoint. Then paste it into a RichTextArea. then they export all those info into an Excel (XLS) file. But sometimes, those pasted info aren't reported, or generate some HTML Tags (not understandable for most users).

**What I had suggested** : The RichTextArea has some tools, displayed with buttons, one of them is "Remove Formatting", if they press it, everything would be ok. But I had to agree with them, it isn't intuitive and "friendly" to use. Since they are my clients, I want to help them as much as possible.

**What I want** : I want that if they copy paste into the RichTextArea:

- They should be invited to remove the format (with a notification on paste) by pressing the Remove Formatting Button, so I should valorize it.
- Or automatically apply the remove formatting on paste.

But I couldn't achieve those solutions because I don't know how to detect the action of pasting, moreover, for the second solution, I couldn't retrieve on the code the remove formatting action.

Can you help me in order to achieve this please? Any tips that doesn't involve an other technology would be appreciated :)

Aynath

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant:

Not sure about the first approach. But the first thing that comes to my mind is to **use usual change event**. When user will paste the new text, you will be notified that values were changed. Then use any tool to **clean HTML** and get the simple text (I suggest to use something like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/) because it is the easiest thing). Or, if you need something specific implement your own parser/cleaner. The last thing is to simply **set a new text to the current area value**.

Otherwise, you can use Vaadin add-ons which may provide such information. Just look for add-ons repository for CKEditor or TinyMCE Editor